# How to work past "At most one record can be returned by this subquery"

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I'm having trouble understanding this error through all the researching I have done. I have the following query

```
SELECT M.[PO Concatenate], Sum(M.SumofAward) AS TotalAward, (SELECT TOP 1 M1.[Material Group] FROM 
[MGETCpreMG] AS M1 WHERE M1.[PO Concatenate]=M.[PO Concatenate] ORDER BY M1.SumofAward DESC) AS TopGroup
FROM MGETCpreMG AS M
GROUP BY M.[PO Concatenate];
```

For a brief instance it reviews the results I want, but then the "At most one record can be returned by this subquery" error comes and wipes all the data to #Name?

For context, [MGETCpreMG] is a query off a main table [MG ETC] that was used to consolidate Award for differing Material Groups on a PO transaction ([PO Concatenate])

```
SELECT [MG ETC].[PO Concatenate], Sum([MG ETC].Award) AS SumOfAward, [MG ETC].[Material Group]
FROM [MG ETC]
GROUP BY [MG ETC].[PO Concatenate], [MG ETC].[Material Group]
ORDER BY [MG ETC].[PO Concatenate];
```

I'm thinking it lies in my inability to understand how to utilize a subquery.

Comment: https://collingszone.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/%E2%80%98at-most-one-record-can-be-returned-by-this-subquery%E2%80%99-on-select-top-1/

Comment: You can use this to find problematic matches: `SELECT [PO Concatenate] FROM [MGETCpreMG] GROUP BY [PO Concatenate] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: @shawnt00 I've combed through your link and Allen's Browne's website and still could not find the solution to my problem. Your latest code did help me identify problematic matches, but due to the nature of my dataset, there will be PO Concatenates repeating. Perhaps I will have to use a different table/query that has no duplicates of PO Concatenate

Answer (score 0):

In the case in which the query can return more then one value? Simply add an additonal sort by.

So, a common  sub query might be to get the last invoice. So you might have:

```
select ID, CompanyName,
  (SELECT TOP 1 InvoiceDate from tblInvoice 
   where tblInvoice.CustomerID = tblCompany.ID
   Order by InvoiceDate DESC)
  As LastInvoiceDate
From tblCustomers
```

Now the above might work for some time, but then it will blow up since you might have two invoices for the same day!

So, all you have to do is add that extra order by clause - say on the PK of the child table like this:

```
   Order by InvoiceDate DESC,ID DESC)
```

So top 1 will respect the "additional" order columns you add, and thus only ever return one row - even if there are multiple values that match the top 1 column.

I suppose in the above we could perhaps forget the invoiceDate and always take the top most last autonumber ID, but for a lot of queries, you can't always be sure - it might be we want the last most expensive invoice amount. And again, if the max value (top) was the same for two large invoice amounts, then again two rows could be return. So, simply add the extra ORDER BY clause with an 2nd column that further orders the data. And thus top 1 will only pull the first value. Your example of a top group is such an example. Just tack on the extra order by "ID" or whatever the auto number ID column is.